# Fréchet differentiable non-reflexive Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Consider $X$ a Banach space and its continuous dual $X^*$. We know that if the dual norm $\|\cdot\|^*$ of $X^*$ is Fréchet differentiable then $X$ is reflexive (e.g., see [Theorem 8.6](https://books.google.com/books?id=Hcqm4_lW4EkC&pg=PA244) in

*Fabian, Marián; Habala, Petr; Hájek, Petr; Montesinos Santalucía, Vicente; Pelant, Jan; Zizler, Václav*, Functional analysis and infinite-dimensional geometry, New York, NY: Springer. ix, 451 p. (2001). [ZBL0981.46001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0981.46001).)

If the norm $\|\cdot\|$ of $X$ is Frechet differentiable, does it imply that $X$ is reflexive? If not, could we construct a non-reflexive space $X$ such that $\|\cdot\|$ is Frechet differentiable?

Comment: The space $c_0(\mathbb N_0)$ with the supremum norm has an equivalent norm that is infinitely times Fréchet differentiable on the open set of nonzero vectors.